# RadGrid column - Get nonrounded value

Tags: c#, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I have column, where I bind values like 1234.567 and I display them like 1235.
But in code behind, I want real value (1234.567)

```
Dim item As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p7", SqlDbType.Float).Value = item("column7").Text
```

Problem is, I get rounded value here. How to get 1234.567?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are displaying by formatting it to a whole numbers, you won't be able to retrieve it from the grid that way in the code behind.

To work around this issue:

1. Add another column to the Radgrid (with the non-rounded number)
2. Set the Display = False on that column

Then use that new column in the code-behind.